# Setting LmCompatibilityLevel in Registry Editor is same as changing Local Security Policy?

Tags: batch-file, local-security-policy

I would like to write a batch script to change the

> Local Security Policy -> LAN Manager Authentication Level

to "Send LM & NTLM - use the NTLMv2 session security if negotiated".
I added the following statement to my batch script to achieve this:

```
reg add HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\LmCompatibilityLevel /t REG_SZ /d 1 /f
```

I can see in the registry editor that the value was updated, however when I go to

> Local Security Policy -> Local Policies -> Security Options -> Network security LAN Manager -> Authentication level

the security setting still shows up as "Not Defined" instead of "Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated".

[image: Click to see image]

Am I doing something wrong?
Is there another way to automate this using a batch script?

Referenced Article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/network-security-lan-manager-authentication-level

Comment: SecEdit accesses the registry where no one has access. You have to take ownership of that tree, add yourself as a user. But in past experiments I have not been able to make anything take. You are changing a setting not a security option.

Comment: Local Policy settings are not stored in registry, they are stored in policy files `.pol` in `%SystemRoot%\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine|User` folders. Registry security policies will applied to registry by using `Registry.pol` file. You see the setting as `Not Defined` because the policy is not defined in `Registry.pol` file. Every policy setting in registry will be overwritten by corresponding setting in policy file and remain as is if it has not been defined in the policy file. Since there is no policy defined for `LmCompatibilityLevel` the setting that you set in registry will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Your registry value is wrong type (`/t REG_SZ` in your `reg add` command). It is a `REG_DWORD` value, so your `LmCompatibilityLevel` added value is ignored.

Try instead:

```
/t REG_DWORD
```

Otherwise you could also use domain group policy instead of a batch script.

Answer (score -1):

reg.exe add HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\ /v LmCompatibilityLevel /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f